# Parametrización de web.config .Net

Tags: asp.net, webservice, windows-server-2012

Quería saber si es posible parametrizar valores  en alguna herramienta de Windows server o otra, de manera que un servicio soap o rest los consuma, la idea es no utilizar un Web.config.

Agradezco sus comentarios

Comment: Puedes explicar un poco mas la pregunta no se entiende

Comment: Normalmente cuando  instalamos un servicio web en el IIS se crea un archivo de configuración, allí obtenemos la cadena de conexión y otras variables, el problema que me plantean es : No usar el archivo de configuración para obtener estas variables, sino encontrar la forma de obtener de otro lado (que no sea de una base de datos), encontré que se puede a travez de las variables de entorno, se me ocurre que sería setearlas ahí y que el servicio web las consuma de ahí, no se sea una buena idea.

Comment: Mi pregunta es porque no quieres usar web.config ?? lo ves inseguro o porque ahi se guardan las conexiones se puede tener acceso a todo o no se?

Comment: Es correcto, se tiene acceso a todo

Comment: No se si te sirva encriptar el web cofig

Comment: @RaulCacacho Gracias, revisaré de esa manera

Comment: si te sirve así puede hacerte un ejemplo de guia